# fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'criterion'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working with `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) is the link to it.
I want to use the keyword `criterion` and set it to `"entropy"`

I did the following :

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, criterion = "entropy")
```

but it gives this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-509174b2caad> in <module>()
      1 model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 2 model.fit(X_train, y_train, criterion = "entropy")

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'criterion'
```

It is working fine with the default argument `'gini'` but not with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy")
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Oh that's so stupid of me. Thank you it worked.
So do I to have pass other arguments while declaring the model?

Comment: Actually, you can consult the docs to check which parameters are used for which function (or use Shift+Tab directly in Jupyter after you type function name). The parameters you see in the [signature](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) of the constructor should be passed in the constructor. [fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit) accepts other parameters (sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted).